# How should I extend a generic repository

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern

Trying to understand if I can extend a Generic Repository Interface or not.

Sorry, I'm new to this and have google search this and can't find any such implementation which leads me to think I'm trying to defy the generic repository logic.

I'm using EF Core ORM.

I have `IRepository<T>`:

```
IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
T Get(long id);
void Insert(T entity);       
void Update(T entity);
void Delete(T entity);
```

I then implement a Generic Repository:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
```

However I need to implement a special method for ONLY one entity name `Conference` such as:

```
IList<T> GetIncludedItems(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, params string[] navigationProperties);
```

How can I extend my Generic Repository to handle that one exception method without having the other entities implementing it. In addition, my `service class` will be implementing these `Repositories` via constructor injection.

```
public ConferenceService(IRepository<Conference> _conferenceRepository )
```

I also need to maintain Dependency binding via my `ConfigurServices`.

```
services.AddScoped<IConferenceService, ConferenceService>();
```

Any suggestion where I'm going wrong or how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework or is this a wrapper around some other ORM?

Comment: You should make a special repository `ConferenceRepository : IConferenceRepository<Conference>` which also derives from `IRepository`

Comment: I'd recommend **against** attempting to hide EF through a Repository Pattern. EF on itself follows the Repository Pattern so you would be doing the Repository of a Repository => disaster

Comment: Yes. I'm using EF Core, .NET Core on a MVC project.
@FCin - I did that but realize I have to re-implement all the methods that the Repository<T> already implemented. Trying to avoid redundant work.

Comment: You should use EF directly and leave the Repository paterrn for a non-ORM implementation.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Actually you are right. Repository pattern makes it difficult to combine multiple entities and create joins. zXSwordXz I would advise you to use services instead of repository pattern. I had a similar question a couple of days ago.

Comment: The type `DbContext` is an implementation of a UoW pattern and the type `DbSet<T>` is an implementation of a Repository pattern. Why re-wrap these types in your own implementation of the same pattern? You are adding nothing of value, just more code and a poor abstraction which results in code that is harder to read, debug, and use.

Comment: Thank you all for your input.  I do realize that with this pattern I'm over complicating my code. However, I was able to solve it and will post the URL below just in case someone goes down this rabbit hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution to my problem, I need to inherit the base repository if I want to add a custom method for a specific entity. 
[click here to see how to solve the above problem](http://techbrij.com/generic-repository-unit-of-work-entity-framework-unit-testing-asp-net-mvc)